# Segregate the query to return data in grouped format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which returns data, so far so good. I want to group the output based on the `degreeID`.

I can do with code to output it but i want the database to get this down for me, I a trying to find a solution but could not find one, here is my query:

```
select 
    sp.Name, sp.WebUrl, P.DegreeID, D.DegreeName, P.ProgramName
from 
    sitepage sp
left join 
    dbo.ProgramCatalogs PC on PC.ProgramID = SP.ProgramID 
                           and  PC.IsCurrentLive = 1
left join 
    Programs P on PC.ProgramId = P.ProgramID
left join 
    Degrees D on P.DegreeID = D.DegreeID
where 
    sp.PageType = 2 and sp.Active = 'True'
```

The `DegreeID` and `DegreeName` can be common and have same id and name for multiple programs, so how can I use group and display them like a `ul > li` as we do in html?

Comment: I can't give an exact answer, because you showed us neither input nor output data, but I will say that what you want to do is probably best handled in your presentation layer.  Just add an `ORDER BY` clause and then iterate the result set to generate the HTML you want.

Comment: I id added order by and i am using **ColdFusion** `cfoutput` to display results using a `group` attribute

Comment: but the problem, i want the output in JSON, the same way I am trying to show in my Page, like this screen http://prntscr.com/ilnq2x

Comment: i tried using sql server `FOR JSOn PATH` but i do not have enough idea how  that is working

Comment: You really need to show us some data.

Comment: you mean the sql data, if that is here is the sample attached: